# How to shuffle two numpy arrays, such that the correspondence between shuffled arrays is the same as the original arrays

Tags: python, numpy, shuffle

So I have two np arrays: namely `Labels` and `Images`

The shape of `Labels` is (3000,1), and the shape of `Images` is (3000, 226,226,3). The ith label corresponds to the ith image. Now I want to shuffle my dataset such that the correspondence is preserved. Is there a python library or function for this task?

One idea I got was to concatenate the labels and images into one array, and then shuffle the resulting matrix by axis = 0. However, `np.concatenate()` did not allow it because the shape of the arrays is not the same.

Comment: Shuffle 3000 integer indices and use them to rearrange Labels and Images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in at least 2 ways.

You can shuffle indices and use advanced indexing (sub optimal with memory)

```
indices = np.arange(len(images))
np.random.shuffle(indices)
images = images[indices]
labels = labels[indices]
```

But I think the best is resetting the seed before each shuffle to allow in place shuffle:

```
# make sure images and labels are shuffled in place and in unison
s = 42 # or whatever
np.random.seed(s)
np.random.shuffle(images)
np.random.seed(s)
np.random.shuffle(labels)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a similar approach to @Julian 's answer, but using numpy's now more recommended random number generator:

```
# There is no need to specify a random seed, 
# but to generate an unpredictable one.
seed = np.random.SeedSequence()
np.random.default_rng(seed).shuffle(images)
np.random.default_rng(seed).shuffle(labels)
```

Answer (score 0):

combine two array together and shuffle it

```
tmp = list(zip(images, labels))
np.random.shuffle(tmp)
images, labels = zip(*tmp)
```

Comment: OP said that array are not the same length but `zip` will only go as far a the length of the shortest array. So you'll be losing some data. You can maybe do this using `itertools.zip_longest()` instead

Comment: @NotAName in this problem. if images and lables not equal, it is a data problem.

Comment: @NotAName The first dimension of two arrays has the same size, so their lengths are the same.